# undefined is returned in JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, undefined

When I call this function, sending for example: abc as the parameter,
the function returns: undefinedcba.  I can't figure out why it's adding
'undefined' to my returned value.  I'm probably overlooking something obvious
but I can't spot it.  Thank you.

```
function FirstReverse(str) { 
    var str_arr1 = new Array();
    var ans = '';
    for(i=0; i < str.length; i++) {
        str_arr1.push(str.charAt(i));
    }
    for(j=str.length; j >= 0; j--) {
        ans += str_arr1[j];
    }
    return ans; 
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Strings are 0-indexed.  `str[str.length]` does not exist.

`j` needs to start at `str.length - 1`.

Or, just `return str_arr1.join();`

Comment: Or he could just rewrite his function to: `function FirstReverse(str) { 
    return str.split("").reverse().join("");
}`

Answer (score 1):

The index of the string starts at 0, so `string.length` is always one number bigger than index  of the last character in the string.

In the second for loop, use

```
for(var j=str.length -1; j >= 0; j--) {
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the second `for` statement. See the solution:

```
function FirstReverse(str) { 
    var str_arr1 = new Array();
    var ans = '';
    for(i=0; i < str.length; i++) {
        str_arr1.push(str.charAt(i));
    }
    for(j=str.length-1; j >= 0; j--) {
        ans += str_arr1[j];
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because when you pass 'abc' there are only 3 characters in it. 
So arrray `str_arr` have elements at index 0, 1 and 2. 
But you are looping for `str.length` i.e. for 3 times and `str_arr[3]` is not defined.

You should do this,

```
function FirstReverse(str) {  
  var str_arr1 = new Array();
  var ans = '';
  for(i=0; i < str.length; i++) {
    str_arr1.push(str.charAt(i));
  }
  for(j=str.length-1; j >= 0; j--) {
    ans += str_arr1[j];
  }
  return ans;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to reverse a string, which you can do in this javascript one liner

```
function reverse(s){
    return s.split("").reverse().join("");
}
```

The reason you are getting an undefined is because your `j` starts with `str.length`, whereas it should be `str.length-1. str_arr1[str.length]` is out of bounds and therefore will be undefined.